# Will thread token impact the ref Id formula field after activation?

Tags: community

Hello Community Members,
I am using a custom formula field ("ref:_xxxxxxnWGv._xxxxxxxxx:ref") on case to capture the ref Id for emails which are sent via flow (not email2case). I would like to understand the impact of the new feature "Disable Thread ID and transition to new email thread token" on the custom field.

Will my custom ref Id field continue to work as it is working currently?

Note - I know we can get the thread token via email to flow functionality, but I would rather stick with the custom field instead of making changes to my all-existing flows.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

No, [Ref Id will stop working](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.support_email_to_case_threading.htm&type=5) after you enable the Disable Ref Id Update.

I think the only other way of getting the Thread Token is via the Apex method [getFormattedThreadingToken(CaseId)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.248.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_EmailMessages_getFormattedThreadingToken.htm),

You'll have write logic that invokes that apex method and writes the output of that method to a custom field.  Then you should be able to reference the custom field in your formula field.